# C# Read all response from an HTTP response Windows System.Net.Http

Tags: c#, system.net

This is my method, an async HTTP POST :

```
using System;                               //main data types
using System.Net.Http;                      //for HTTP client
using System.Threading.Tasks;               //for Async Request/Response
using Newtonsoft.Json;                      //for JSON properties

//... the call..
public void Something()
{
PostConsentAsync(cnsnt.BaseURL, cnsnt.Headers, cnsnt.Body).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

//... the async task...
public async Task HttpPostAsync(Uri HTTPaddress, cHeaders myHeaders, cBody myBody)
{
    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding utf8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false, throwOnInvalidBytes: true);

        using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, HTTPaddress))
        {
            client.BaseAddress = HTTPaddress;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SomeHeader", myHeaders.SomeHeader);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("MyOtherHeader", myHeaders.MyOtherHeader);
            //etc..

            request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myBody, Formatting.Indented), utf8, "application/json");

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                Int32 code = (Int32)response.StatusCode;

                //How to read ALL the response, including headers, body etc???

                Console.WriteLine("03\r\nRESPONSE: {0}", response.RequestMessage.ToString() + "\r\nBody:\r\n" + <?????> + "Response HTTP status: " + code + " [" + response.StatusCode.ToString() + "]");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error in " + e.TargetSite + "\r\n" + e.Message); Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I need to read all the response, but seems difficult...
I need to have the whole response message and, in addition, in some form like response. so that I can feed this to another HTTP request. So I was trying to get the whole response and somehow feed it in a class and have something like response.myHeader1.Name (name of header) or response.myHeader1.Value (value of that header, null if null) etc, or something like this. But I can't get the whole message, I get the headers, I get the code (i.e. 200 is success etc) but the body is not there etc.

Answer (score 1):

In order to retrieve the body, you need to access the [Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.content?view=netframework-4.8) property of `HttpResponseMessage`, for example:

`var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`

Comment: The OP is asking how to get the raw response returned by the server, not just the content

Comment: @Pedro: Excellent, indeed body is retrieved. By itself is a significant leap forward for me. However, I would need the whole thing, some headers have values that I need to read (among other things, hopefully all the info in the response message from the server)
Thank you for your insight!

Comment: oh, I misread that you were able to get the Headers and Status code already and only the body was missing. Pulling them out of response.Headers and response.StatusCode is not enough?